# Zero frequency limit of Hall conductivity not quantized?

Tags: condensed-matter, solid-state-physics, electrical-resistance, topological-insulators, quantum-hall-effect

The transverse conductivity $\sigma_{xy}$ at zero frequency is quantized when the chemical potential $\mu$ is within the gap for a topological system, such as quantum Hall effect and Haldane model. Another closely related quantity is the (optical) Hall conductivity $\sigma_H(\omega)=[\sigma_{xy}(\omega)-\sigma_{yx}(\omega)]/2$ for general $\omega$. In many cases, e.g., systems with $C_4$ rotation symmetry, we have $\sigma_H(\omega)=\sigma_{xy}(\omega)$. So Let's ignore their difference here.

This [PRL paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/1111.4471) calculates $\sigma_H(\omega)$ in the following figure (blue for the real part) at some $\mu$, which merely applied the standard Kubo formula to a BdG superconductor.
[image]

Why is the $\omega=0$ limit not quantized at all? Even if the system may not be topological, it can be just zero. My understanding is that $\mu$ is by construction in the gap in a BdG system. So if we write down its Hall conductivity, where is it different from the Chern number? Or put in other words, how is the link between Hall conductivity and Chern number broken in the present case which is not an insulator?

Comment: $\sigma_H$ is quantized in a charge insulator. The plot is for a superconductor, so there is no reason for the Hall conductance to quantize.

Comment: @MengCheng Yes, I think it must be some conceptual flaw in my understanding. But I don't get the difference clearly. I think $\mu$ is inside the gap of a BdG system; so if we write down its Hall conductivity, where is it different from the Chern number?

Comment: The Hall conductance is no longer the "Chern number" of the BdG bands.